# if string in pandas series contains a string from another pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Struggling newbie.
If I have two pandas dataframes  something like :

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = {'col1': ['black sphynx bob','brown labrador','grey labrador mervin',
            'brown siamese cat','white siamese']}
    desc_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

    catg = {'dog': ['labrador','rottweiler',
            'beagle'],'cat':['siamese','sphynx','ragdoll']}

    catg_df = pd.DataFrame(data=catg)

    desc_df
               col1
    0      black spyhnx bob
    1        brown labrador
    2  grey labrador mervin
    3     brown siamese cat
    4         white Siamese

   catg_df
         cat         dog
   0  siamese    labrador
   1   sphynx  rottweiler
   2  ragdoll      beagle
```

I'd like to end up with desc_df dataframe:

```
           col1             col2
0      black spyhnx bob     cat
1        brown Labrador     dog
2  grey labrador Mervin     dog
3     brown siamese cat     cat 
4         white Siamese     cat
```

I thought I maybe could use the apply method with a function. I'm just not 100% confident if that is the best way to approach this and how exactly it could be done.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `str.contains` + `np.where`

```
desc_df['col2']=np.where(desc_df.col1.str.contains(catg_df.cat.str.cat(sep='|')),'cat','dog')
desc_df
Out[1538]: 
                   col1 col2
0      black spyhnx bob  dog
1        brown labrador  dog
2  grey labrador mervin  dog
3     brown siamese cat  cat
4         white siamese  cat
```

OK update for multiple condition

```
d=catg_df.apply('|'.join).to_dict()
desc_df.col1.apply(lambda x : ''.join([z if pd.Series(x).str.contains(y).values else '' for z,y in d.items()]))
Out[1568]: 
0       
1    dog
2    dog
3    cat
4    cat
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: A sphynx is a dog :)

Comment: Thanks, this looks close for some reason the syphnx is coming up as dog. I'll try and understand what you have done. Also this is very simplified of what I am trying to achieve and I have a few more categories than just cat and dog, if it could use the column header that would be awesome.

Comment: @CGully your example spell wrong right ?syphnx or  spyhnx

Comment: @CGully after you fix it , it should give you correct output

Comment: @CGully, if you have any number of columns, e.g. cat / dog / fish / bird / etc, then have a look at my solution. But I'm sure Wen can come up with a generic pandas solution too.

Comment: thanks works great for just two columns. If I have 6 columns this looks to struggle. I'll take a look @jpp solutions. Thanks

Comment: Pretty awesome, it may take me some time to digest. One last thing how to make case insensitive?

Comment: @CGully what you mean make case insensitive

Comment: Apologies,  if someone has used SYPHNX or Syphnx, for either in the desc_df or the catg_df. Many thanks.

Comment: Apologies for such a newb but struggling to know where/how to add str.upper. Thanks again

Comment: @CGully before you run the code `desc_df=desc_df.apply(lambda x : x.str.upper());
catg_df=catg_df.apply(lambda x : x.str.upper())` also, if it helps can you consider accept, check mark in left

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a dictionary mapping animals to type.

Then use `pd.Series.apply` with `next` and a generator expression:

```
d = {i: k for k in catg_df for i in catg_df[k].unique()}

desc_df['col2'] = desc_df['col1'].apply(lambda x: next((d.get(i) for i in x.split() \
                                                        if i in d), None))

print(desc_df)

#                    col1 col2
# 0      black sphynx bob  cat
# 1        brown labrador  dog
# 2  grey labrador mervin  dog
# 3     brown siamese cat  cat
# 4         white siamese  cat
```